# How to fastly upload a directory in MinIO using python SDK?

Tags: python, thread-safety, minio

When using `mc` commands to upload a directory with many small files:
`./mc cp --recursive test/small_file_1024 local/test`
It took within a second to finish.

However, if I use `fput_object()` or `put_object()`, which is provided by python-SDK, I have to iterate the directory and upload the file one by one, taking ten times as long as the previous method.
Is there any way to optimize the code? If not, can I just use `mc` in the `python` script without caring about thread-safe problem?